# No such table Stages error in flutter sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

Good evening, everyone, I got a strange error on my SQLite database no such table: Stages in 'select * from Stages' although the database is opened and there is an attached screen that shows my query on SQLlite studio and I have another database with the same name of the table and it works !! and that's my code

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:mo3lmty/Modules/Categories.dart';
import 'package:mo3lmty/Modules/Drawer.dart';
import 'package:mo3lmty/Screens/draw_letters.dart';
import 'package:mo3lmty/Screens/examples_letters.dart';
import 'package:mo3lmty/Screens/expand_list.dart';
import 'package:mo3lmty/Screens/match_screen.dart';
import 'package:mo3lmty/Screens/numbers_screen.dart';
import 'package:mo3lmty/Screens/reading_letters.dart';
import 'package:mo3lmty/Screens/complete.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  String? category;
  String? age;
  String? dbName;
  String? path;

  HomeScreen({super.key, this.category, this.age, this.dbName});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String? database;
  late Future<List> futureData;
  late String databaseName;
  String? databasesPath;

  late BannerAd _bannerAd;
  InterstitialAd? _interstitialAd;
  bool isloaded = false;
  void loadinterad() {
    InterstitialAd.load(
        adUnitId: "ca-app-pub-2483803582097264/4165779011",
        request: const AdRequest(),
        adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
          onAdLoaded: (InterstitialAd ad) {
            // Keep a reference to the ad so you can show it later.
            _interstitialAd = ad;
          },
          onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError e) {
            "Error {$e}";
          },
        ));
  }

  void showInterad() {
    if (_interstitialAd == null) {
      return;
    }
    _interstitialAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
        onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad) {},
        onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad) {
          ad.dispose();
        },
        onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent:
            (InterstitialAd ad, AdError aderror) {
          ad.dispose();
          loadinterad();
        });
    _interstitialAd!.show();
    _interstitialAd = null;
  }

  loadbanner() {
    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
        size: AdSize.banner,
        adUnitId: "ca-app-pub-2483803582097264/5670432370",
        listener: BannerAdListener(
            onAdLoaded: (ad) {
              setState(() {
                isloaded = true;
              });
            },
            onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {}),
        request: const AdRequest());
    _bannerAd.load();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    database = "${widget.age!}_${widget.dbName!}";
    prepareDatabase();
    futureData = fetchData();
    loadbanner();
    showInterad();
    loadinterad();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Release decoders and buffers back to the operating system making them
    // available for other apps to use.
    _bannerAd.dispose();
    _interstitialAd!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future prepareDatabase() async {
    widget.path = join('assets/Thumbs/', '$database.db');
    try {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      databaseName = '$database.db';
      databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
      //get DB from assets and load it
      var dbDir = await getDatabasesPath();
      var dbPath = join(dbDir, "$database.db");

      if (File(dbPath).existsSync()) {
      } else {
        ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/Thumbs/$database.db');
        List<int> bytes =
            data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
        await File(dbPath).writeAsBytes(bytes);
      }
      await fetchData();
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      "Error {$e}";
    }
  }

  Future<List> fetchData() async {
    var dbDir = await getDatabasesPath();
    var dbPath = join(dbDir, "$database.db");
    final db = await openDatabase(dbPath, version: 2);
    return db.rawQuery('select * from Stages');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                widget.category.toString(),
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontFamily: 'El Messiri'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  colors: <Color>[
                    Color.fromRGBO(78, 84, 200, 1.0),
                    Color.fromRGBO(127, 133, 239, 1.0),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        drawer: const DrawerWidget(),
        bottomNavigationBar: isloaded
            ? Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: _bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
                height: _bannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),
                child: AdWidget(
                  ad: _bannerAd,
                ),
              )
            : const SizedBox(),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: futureData,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else {
                return GridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 4.0),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                    Data course = Data.fromMap(snapshot.data[i]);
                    return Container(
                      height: size.height,
                      width: size.width,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 12.0, right: 12.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                      child: Card(
                        shadowColor: Colors.blue[900],
                        elevation: 8.0,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            if (i == 0) {
                              if (database == '3_Arabic') {
                                Get.to(() => ReadingLetters(
                                      category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                      age: widget.age,
                                      dbName: widget.dbName,
                                      tableName: "Reading_Letters",
                                      hassong: true,
                                    ));
                              }
                              if (database == '4_Arabic') {
                                showInterad();
                                loadinterad();
                                Get.to(() => DrawLetters(
                                    category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                    age: widget.age,
                                    dbName: widget.dbName,
                                    tableName: "Writting_Letters"));
                              }
                            }
                            if (i == 1) {
                              if (database == '3_Arabic') {
                                showInterad();
                                loadinterad();
                                Get.to(() => ReadingLetters(
                                      category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                      age: widget.age,
                                      dbName: widget.dbName,
                                      tableName: "Numbers",
                                      hassong: true,
                                    ));
                              }
                              if (database == '4_Arabic') {
                                Get.to(() => DrawLetters(
                                    category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                    age: widget.age,
                                    dbName: widget.dbName,
                                    tableName: "Writing_Numbers"));
                              }
                            }
                            if (i == 2) {
                              if (database == '3_Arabic') {
                                Get.to(() => ReadingLetters(
                                      category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                      age: widget.age,
                                      dbName: widget.dbName,
                                      tableName: "Colors",
                                      hassong: true,
                                    ));
                              }
                              if (database == '4_Arabic') {
                                Get.to(() => Examples(
                                    category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                    age: widget.age,
                                    dbName: widget.dbName,
                                    tableName: "Examples_Letters"));
                              }
                            }
                            if (i == 3) {
                              showInterad();
                              loadinterad();
                              if (database == '3_Arabic') {
                                Get.to(() => ReadingLetters(
                                      category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                      age: widget.age,
                                      dbName: widget.dbName,
                                      tableName: "Shapes",
                                      hassong: true,
                                    ));
                              }
                              if (database == '4_Arabic') {
                                Get.to(() => MatchScreen(
                                      category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                      age: widget.age,
                                      dbName: widget.dbName,
                                      tableName: "Match",
                                    ));
                              }
                            }
                            if (i == 4) {
                              if (database == '3_Arabic') {
                                Get.to(() => ReadingLetters(
                                      category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                      age: widget.age,
                                      dbName: widget.dbName,
                                      tableName: "Fruits",
                                      hassong: true,
                                    ));
                              }
                              if (database == '4_Arabic') {
                                Get.to(() => ReadingLetters(
                                      category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                      age: widget.age,
                                      dbName: widget.dbName,
                                      tableName: "Tongue",
                                      hassong: false,
                                    ));
                              }
                            }
                            if (i == 5) {
                              if (database == '3_Arabic') {
                                Get.to(() => Numbers(
                                      category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                      age: widget.age,
                                      dbName: widget.dbName,
                                      tableName: "Animal_Stages",
                                    ));
                              }
                              if (database == '4_Arabic') {
                                Get.to(() => ExpandList(
                                      category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                      age: widget.age,
                                      dbName: widget.dbName,
                                      tableName: "",
                                    ));
                              }
                            }
                            if (i == 6) {
                              if (database == '3_Arabic') {
                                showInterad();
                                loadinterad();
                                Get.to(() => ReadingLetters(
                                    category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                    age: widget.age,
                                    dbName: widget.dbName,
                                    tableName: "Food_Tools",
                                    hassong: false));
                              }
                              if (database == '4_Arabic') {
                                Get.to(() => CompleteWords(
                                      category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                      age: widget.age,
                                      dbName: widget.dbName,
                                      tableName: "choose",
                                    ));
                              }
                            }
                            if (i == 7) {
                              showInterad();
                              loadinterad();
                              Get.to(() => ReadingLetters(
                                  category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                  age: widget.age,
                                  dbName: widget.dbName,
                                  tableName: "vegetables",
                                  hassong: true));
                            }
                            if (i == 8) {
                              showInterad();
                              loadinterad();
                              Get.to(() => ReadingLetters(
                                  category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                  age: widget.age,
                                  dbName: widget.dbName,
                                  tableName: "Clothes",
                                  hassong: false));
                            }
                            if (i == 9) {
                              Get.to(() => ReadingLetters(
                                  category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                  age: widget.age,
                                  dbName: widget.dbName,
                                  tableName: "Body",
                                  hassong: false));
                            }
                            if (i == 10) {
                              showInterad();
                              loadinterad();
                              Get.to(() => ReadingLetters(
                                  category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                  age: widget.age,
                                  dbName: widget.dbName,
                                  tableName: "Jobs",
                                  hassong: true));
                            }
                            if (i == 11) {
                              Get.to(() => ReadingLetters(
                                  category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                  age: widget.age,
                                  dbName: widget.dbName,
                                  tableName: "Weather",
                                  hassong: true));
                            }
                            if (i == 12) {
                              showInterad();
                              loadinterad();
                              Get.to(() => ReadingLetters(
                                  category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                  age: widget.age,
                                  dbName: widget.dbName,
                                  tableName: "Transportations",
                                  hassong: true));
                            }
                            if (i == 13) {
                              Get.to(() => ReadingLetters(
                                  category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                  age: widget.age,
                                  dbName: widget.dbName,
                                  tableName: "Opposites",
                                  hassong: true));
                            }
                            if (i == 14) {
                              Get.to(() => ReadingLetters(
                                  category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                  age: widget.age,
                                  dbName: widget.dbName,
                                  tableName: "Electrical",
                                  hassong: false));
                            }
                            if (i == 15) {
                              showInterad();
                              loadinterad();
                              Get.to(() => ReadingLetters(
                                  category: course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                  age: widget.age,
                                  dbName: widget.dbName,
                                  tableName: "Furniture",
                                  hassong: true));
                            }
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            // height: 150,
                            // width: 150,
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage(course.Image_Name.toString()),
                                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                      icon: const Icon(
                                        Icons.favorite,
                                        size: 20.5,
                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(78, 84, 200, 1.0),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Flexible(
                                      child: Container(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            right: 8.0, top: 4.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          course.Stage_Name.toString(),
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 13.5,
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontFamily: 'El Messiri'),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                const LinearProgressIndicator(
                                  value: 1.0,
                                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                      Color.fromRGBO(78, 84, 200, 1.0)),
                                  minHeight: 12.0,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

[image: MY Query]

Comment: Be careful... sql tables are case-sensitive, and the API from dart might also be, but `select * from Stages` is the same as `select * from stages`, because in the absence of quoting, names are lowercased.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I tried with lowercase and even changed the name of the table still no such table it was working good but don't know what happened!!

Comment: did you sow this link: https://shriya-apps.medium.com/flutter-database-sqflite-create-table-and-save-data-into-table-6c704366fc35

Comment: @mohammadmobasher I don't what is wrong now but I downgraded the version to sqflite: ^2.0.2 instead of 2.3.2 and It worked!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't what is wrong now but I downgraded the version to sqflite: ^2.3.1 instead of 2.3.2 and It worked!!